# CSS center align DIV keeping text within left aligned?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following DIV distribution:

```
--------------------       --------------------
| large image here |       | large image here |
--------------------       --------------------

      Text one                   Text two
      here                       here
```

Images are within DIVs and texts are within DIVs. I need the text DIVs to be center aligned to the image DIVs but the contents of text DIVs must remain left aligned.

PS: Cannot use fixed width DIVs because it's a fluid content website (uses Bootstrap).

Any idea?

Comment: The width of the text division.. it depends on what? The length of the text or viewport?

Answer (score 0):

**Css flexbox grid with text-align: center**

**Justify-content:** The justify-content property aligns the flexed container's contents on the main axis, which by default(in case of the web) is the horizontal axis.

The **text-align property** in CSS is used for aligning the inner content of a block element.

```css
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}
.flex-container > div {
    flex:1;
}
.text-content {
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
   

 <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <figure><img src="https://i.imgur.com/HPrl3u8.jpg[/img]"></figure>
    <div class="text-content">Text one <br>
      Here </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <figure><img src="https://i.imgur.com/HPrl3u8.jpg[/img]"></figure>
    <div class="text-content"> Text two<br>
      Here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned using fixed width is not acceptable because while it will work in a deskop screen it won't in mobile...

Comment: Please go with The logic, I updated snippet which have no width now. It is work fine with or without width.

Comment: Your code look good when in desktop but in mobile it won't fluid (it supposed to push down the right large image in small screens). I think it may be some kind of incompatibility with Bootstrap. Never mind anyway... I just gave up of centered text block to be left-aligned and just centered it also...

Comment: My current code:

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:auto">
 <div class="home-image">
 <img src="img1.png" class="img-responsive center-block" />
 </div>
 <div class="home-image" style="text-align: center">
 <p>Text 1</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="home-image">
 <img src="img2.png" class="img-responsive center-block" />
 </div>
 <div class="home-image" style="text-align: center">
 <p>Text 2</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

Css Grid is very flexible, following code will provide you a desired result. I am not using the bootstrap and relying on grid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container > * {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.container img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/1c8e8a6e8d1fe52b782b280909abeb38?s=400&d=robohash&r=x" alt="">
    <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/1c8e8a6e8d1fe52b782b280909abeb38?s=400&d=robohash&r=x" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div>
</div>
```